# ^= operator, what does it do?

Tags: c#, operators

I just saw a code where operator `^=` was used in it.
What does it do?
It was used like this:
`number^=arr[m];`
Wher both number and arr[m] are integers.

I would search for it, but it looks impossible to search for ^= .

Comment: Take a look at the [^ operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

Comment: You can read the documentation for the [`^=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zbsw2z6.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's enough information in the official documentation

Comment: I understand, but there was no need to down vote. I just couldn't search for ^ on the internet so I asked it here.

Comment: You can browse the documentation and look for the list of operators

Comment: Down voted due to lack of research effort.

Comment: @farshad No but if you _do_ search for "C# ^= operator" the first result is the MSDN page that lists ALL operators, including `^=`.  It shouldn't have been that hard to find,

Comment: OK. You guys are so tough to beginners here. I'm simply not used to search document. learnt about it just now.

Comment: @farshad -- you may be a beginner to coding, but don't you know how to google?

Comment: well, I agree I had to search more. Just because ^ wasn't in the preview I didn't open the google results. Can anyone delete this post?

Comment: Even beginners are expected to spend some effort searching the documentation.  As D Stanley noted, the first result is a list of all operators.  It wasn't hard to find.

Comment: @farshad don't take it so hard. 2 upvotes on a question can make up for 5 downvotes.  Plus the point is for you to get the answer, not just to get points, right? :)

Comment: @farshad -- if you hover your cursor over the down vote button, the very first reason listed is "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @farshad There's should be a "delete" link under the post if you want to delete it yourself; otherwise it takes a moderator to delete it.

Comment: @DStanley now it has an answer, it won't let me to delete is.

Comment: @farshad Don't sweat it then.  Looks like you got your answer and a net of 4 points so far :)

Comment: Yeah, You're write. Sorry to bother you guys. I'll promise to search harder next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x ^= y
```

is the short version of

```
x = x ^ y
```

and is performing bitwise XOR operation.

Comment: It's not necessarily **bitwise**.

Comment: @Amit.  For integral arguments it is.

Comment: @DStanley - is there anything in this entire post that says it's about integral types?

Comment: @Amit yes. It says "number and arr[m] are integers."

Comment: @Amit I know, i just hoped he doesn't ask about bool parameters. At least he stated so.

Comment: @DStanley - ha! I didn't notice that. Sorry.